# If the unit ball of a sub-space is closed in a coarser topology, this the sub-space also closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, denote the closed unit ball of $X$ by $D_1$ and consider a locally convex Hausdorff topology $\tau$ on $X$ that is coarser than the Banach topology, for example $\tau$ could be the weak topology.

Let $V\subseteq X$ be a vector sub-space, is the following equivalence true?

> $V$ is closed in $\tau$ $\iff$ $V\cap D_1$ is closed in $\tau$.

If $\tau$ comes from a norm the statement is true, as any $\tau$-convergent sequence must then be bounded wrt the original norm, but for a locally convex topology one cannot guarantee the norm-boundedness of a convergent net and the argument doesn't work so simply.

Comment: Please remind me, for the weak topology, wouldn't it still work since weakly bounded sets (such as $D$) are bounded?

Comment: @Chrystomath the weak topology is not sequential, and while convergent sequences need to be weakly bounded the convergent nets do not and I don't think I can apply the argument.

Comment: For the weak topology (and thus for all admissible topologies) the matter is settled by convexity. Recall that a convex set is weakly closed iff it is originally closed, thus $V$ is $\tau$-closed iff it's norm-closed, $V\cap D_1$ is $\tau$-closed iff it's norm-closed, and $V$ is norm-closed iff $V\cap D_1$ is norm-closed. If you go weaker than $\sigma(X,X')$ I suspect that there are counterexamples, but so far I didn't see one.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the remark! Regarding counterexamples, for the weak* topology (if $X$ has a pre-dual) it is not true in general that convex sets are weak* closed iff they are norm closed, for example the weak* closure of $C([0,1])\subseteq B(L^2([0,1]))$ is $L^\infty([0,1])$ where the predual of $B(L^2([0,1]))$ is the space $L_1(L^2([0,1]))$ of trace-class operators.

Comment: Yes, if $Y$ is a non-reflexive Banach space, then $Y$ is norm-closed but not weak$^{\ast}$-closed in $Y''$. I've been looking at such cases. But so far I haven't found a counterexample.

Comment: For the weak$^*$ topology on a dual Banach space the claim follows from the Banach-Dieudonné theorem.

Comment: @Jochen are there any other "classical" lcs topologies on a Banach space one can test the hypothesis for? I know a family of operator topologies on $B(H)$ for $H$ a Hilbert space, but for these the hypothesis is still true by the bicommutant theorem.

Comment: If, for a dual Banach space, $V \cap D_1$ is weak$^*$ closed then it is weak$^*$ compact  and hence closed in any coarser Hausdorff topology $\tau$. The assumption that $V\cap D_1$ is $\tau$-closed is thus equivalent to the weak$^*$ closedness.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are saying is: If $\tau$ is coarser than weak* then $D_1$ is compact and hence $\tau$-closed, this gives $V$ closed $\implies$ $V\cap D_1$ closed. Is the other direction similarly elementary (resp. a corollary of Banach-Dieudonne, which I have not yet fully understood)? If I understand the message of Daniel Fischer above correctly he says the statement is true for any topology finer than the weak topology (is that what admissable means?).